# How can I debug a C Command Line program in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode

Just as the question title, how can I debug a program running on Xcode? I add some breakpoints but after I press the run button, it says build failed and does not stop at the first break point.

Comment: You have to run your program in Xcode.

Comment: From what you say, it seems like you need to get the build working first.

Comment: Now the program build succeeded, but it still cannot stop at the break point.

Comment: And how to see the variables in C program running on XCode? Does anybody know this?

Comment: How can I add initial arguments for a C program running on XCode, which are `char * argv[]` showing in the main function? I mean, when I hit the Run button, it just automatically runs without any argument.